# Trying to insert a previous answer as an x value

Tags: python

```
def Use_Last_Answer():
    choose_opt = input('''Do you want to use the previous answer?  (Y/N)''' )
    if choose_opt.upper() == 'Y': #Function for ANS
        x = ANS
        find_fractions_2
    elif choose_opt.upper() == 'N':
        find_fractions()
    else:
        Use_Last_Answer()

def find_fractions(): 
    x = 0 # makes x reset but not necessary
    x = Fraction(input('''Enter (1st) fraction:'''))
    find_fractions_2()

def find_fractions_2():
    operation = input('''
What do you want to do?
Add         (1) (e.g) 1/5 + 1/10 = 3/10
Enter Function number:''')
    if(operation != '1'):
        print("You must enter a valid operation")
    else:
        y = Fraction(input('''Enter (2nd) fraction:'''))
        if operation == '1':
            print('''Adding Fractions...''')
            print('{} + {} = '.format(x, y)) 
            ANS = print(x + y)
    Use_Last_Answer()
find_fractions()
```

(This isn't the whole code, but just cut down to fit).

I'm trying to make an ANS function which is usually available on calculators by making `ANS = (x+y)` <- from the previous equation and making a def to see whether ANS is able to become x variable. I separated  `def find_functions()` into two parts to bypass `x = Fraction(input('''Enter (1st) fraction:'''))` and go to which operation (e.g) add, subtract etc. making the previous answer the new equations x variable.

But it's not working and when I separate `def find_fractions()` into the two parts and start a new equation the x variable doesn't carry through to the second part and the x+y doesn't compute. I'm in high school and this is my 5th week of computer science, so I won't know too much jargon.

Comment: you should read about global and local variable declarations http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html , and answer to your question define variable ANS outside the methods and make it global

Comment: I'll check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you want to hold something and use it later, your going to want a "global" variable.  These go at the start of your script and any function  will be able to utilize it or change it.

```
ans = 0

def this_changes_ans():
    ans += 0.75

def use_previous():
    If input == "Y":
        ans = ans
    else:
        ans = 0
```

Also ..

```
Ans = print(x + y)
```

just... no

Comment: What does "just... no" mean in this context? It sounds like an expression of exasperation, possibly in jest, but it is not clear what you don't like about the line of code indicated. For the benefit of future readers, could you make that clear, by way of an answer edit?